# Stripe API Update Product wont reset images array to empty

Tags: stripe-payments

As the title says, is this the intended way of Stripe doing the update operation for products? Lets say if you want to delete all links in the images array and during my testing apparently you can not do this unless the array size is >= 1.

I wanted to delete all links in the array hence i **sent an empty images array** but Stripe wont update the array to an empty array. I used this Stripe API [Stripe Update Product API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/products/update).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set an empty array for `images` once an image has been added to the Product. You can only overwrite the array by setting at least 1 new element in the array. Once `images` has been updated, it will replace the old array with the new one.

If you need to delete the images from that Product, you can do so via the Stripe dashboard. Navigate to the Product you want to edit and click the "Edit" button:
[image: Product view]
Then click the "x" icon to delete the image:
[image]